# How to take a powershell output and copy files to it?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files to any local drive with volume named "Data", but I am unsure how to parse out the drive letter for the copy.

This is the line I am using to grab the volumes:

```
$drive=Get-WmiObject -class Win32_logicaldisk | 
    Where-Object {$_.VolumeName -eq "Data"} |
    select DeviceID
```

Then I want to do an xcopy from `c:\temp` to `$drive/backupfolder` (this is where it fails as `$drive` shows

```
DeviceId
--------
D:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$drive` isn't a string. But an Object with the property `DeviceId` which is a string. You can either expand the property

```
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk | 
    Where-Object {$_.VolumeName -eq "Data"} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceID
```

Or expand the property this way:

```
$drive = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk | Where-Object {$_.VolumeName -eq "Data"}).DeviceID
```

Or reference the property on the variable:

```
"$($drive.DeviceID)\backupfolder"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply and answer!

Comment: Commenting to mention the best way to discover those properties is to pipe them to `Get-Member` in this example simply do `$drive | Get-Member` and look at the available items under `MemberType`